# MySQL grouping view

Tags: mysql

I have table recap like this. This table is used for recap data education in my organization.
I using mysql 5

```
    mysql> select * from rekap_teams.tblrekappendidikan_divisitahunan;
+----+------------------------------------+-------+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+-------+
| id | divisi                             | year  | SD | SMP | SMA | D1 | D2 | D3 | S1  | S2 | S3 | total |
+----+------------------------------------+-------+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+-------+
|  1 | CORPORATE                          |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  25 |  4 |  0 |    29 |
|  2 | CORPORATE SERVICES                 |  2014 |  0 |   0 | 137 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 195 |  4 |  1 |   340 |
|  3 | FINANCE                            |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  2 |  54 |  2 |  0 |    59 |
|  4 | SALES 1                            |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  19 |  0 |  0 |    19 |
|  5 | SALES 2                            |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  2 |  0 |    12 |
|  6 | PROMOTION                          |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  25 |  1 |  0 |    27 |
|  7 | NON DIVISION - SALES & MARKETING   |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  66 |  1 |  0 |    67 |
|  8 | NON DIVISION - BOARD OF MANAGEMENT |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   1 |  8 |  0 |     9 |
|  9 | PROGRAMMING                        |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  28 |  3 |  0 |    32 |
| 10 | OPERATIONAL BROADCAST              |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   4 |  0 |  9 |  9 | 376 |  3 |  0 |   401 |
| 11 | NON DIVISION                       |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |     0 |
| 12 | PRODUCTION 1                       |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 124 |  1 |  0 |   129 |
| 13 | PRODUCTION 2                       |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  5 |  3 | 109 |  1 |  0 |   119 |
| 14 | FILM, DRAMA & SPORT                |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  4 |  76 |  1 |  0 |    82 |
| 15 | NEWS                               |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  4 |  5 | 218 |  5 |  0 |   232 |
| 16 | PRODUCTION FACILITIES              |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   2 |  0 |  4 | 13 | 597 |  5 |  0 |   621 |
| 17 | PRODUCTION 4                       |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  2 |  40 |  0 |  0 |    42 |
| 18 | PCDC                               |  2014 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   5 |  0 |  0 |     5 |
| 19 | CORPORATE                          |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  26 |  3 |  0 |    29 |
| 20 | CORPORATE SERVICES                 |  2015 |  0 |   0 | 130 |  0 |  1 |  1 | 194 |  2 |  1 |   329 |
| 21 | FINANCE                            |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  49 |  2 |  0 |    53 |
| 22 | SALES 1                            |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  18 |  0 |  0 |    18 |
| 23 | SALES 2                            |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  2 |  0 |    12 |
| 24 | PROMOTION                          |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  25 |  1 |  0 |    27 |
| 25 | NON DIVISION - SALES & MARKETING   |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  64 |  1 |  0 |    65 |
| 26 | NON DIVISION - BOARD OF MANAGEMENT |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   1 |  8 |  0 |     9 |
| 27 | PROGRAMMING                        |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  27 |  3 |  0 |    31 |
| 28 | OPERATIONAL BROADCAST              |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   3 |  0 |  9 |  7 | 369 |  2 |  0 |   390 |
| 29 | NON DIVISION                       |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |     0 |
| 30 | PRODUCTION 1                       |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 117 |  1 |  0 |   122 |
| 31 | PRODUCTION 2                       |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  5 |  2 | 106 |  1 |  0 |   115 |
| 32 | FILM, DRAMA & SPORT                |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  4 |  72 |  1 |  0 |    78 |
| 33 | NEWS                               |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  4 |  5 | 211 |  5 |  0 |   225 |
| 34 | PRODUCTION FACILITIES              |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   2 |  0 |  2 |  6 | 583 |  5 |  0 |   598 |
| 35 | PRODUCTION 4                       |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  36 |  0 |  0 |    36 |
| 36 | PCDC                               |  2015 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   4 |  0 |  0 |     4 |
+----+------------------------------------+-------+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+-------+
36 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i alwasy try to solve my problem with grouping query. but i stack, How the query create view like this?

```
+------------------------------------+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
| DIVISI                             |               2014            |               2015            |
+                                    +----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
|                                    | SD | SMP | SMA | D1 | D2 | D3 | S1  | S2 | S3 | SD | SMP | SMA | D1 | D2 | D3 | S1  | S2 | S3 |
+------------------------------------+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
| CORPORATE                          |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  25 |  4 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  25 |  4 |  0 |
| CORPORATE SERVICES                 |  0 |   0 | 137 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 195 |  4 |  1 |  0 |   0 | 137 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 195 |  4 |  1 |
| FILM, DRAMA & SPORT                |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  4 |  76 |  1 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  4 |  76 |  1 |  0 |
| FINANCE                            |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  2 |  54 |  2 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  2 |  54 |  2 |  0 |
| NEWS                               |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  4 |  5 | 218 |  5 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  4 |  5 | 218 |  5 |  0 |
| NON DIVISION                       |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |
| NON DIVISION - BOARD OF MANAGEMENT |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   1 |  8 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   1 |  8 |  0 |
| NON DIVISION - SALES & MARKETING   |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  66 |  1 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  66 |  1 |  0 |
| OPERATIONAL BROADCAST              |  0 |   0 |   4 |  0 |  9 |  9 | 376 |  3 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   4 |  0 |  9 |  9 | 376 |  3 |  0 |
| PCDC                               |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   5 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   5 |  0 |  0 |
| PRODUCTION 1                       |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 124 |  1 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  1 |  2 | 124 |  1 |  0 |
| PRODUCTION 2                       |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  5 |  3 | 109 |  1 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  5 |  3 | 109 |  1 |  0 |
| PRODUCTION 4                       |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  2 |  40 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  2 |  40 |  0 |  0 |
| PRODUCTION FACILITIES              |  0 |   0 |   2 |  0 |  4 | 13 | 597 |  5 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   2 |  0 |  4 | 13 | 597 |  5 |  0 |
| PROGRAMMING                        |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  28 |  3 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  28 |  3 |  0 |
| PROMOTION                          |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  25 |  1 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  25 |  1 |  0 |
| SALES 1                            |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  19 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  19 |  0 |  0 |
| SALES 2                            |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  2 |  0 |  0 |   0 |   1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  2 |  0 |
+------------------------------------+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you know the years that you have, the following query will get you data in the form you want. Change the field list if you want them in a certain order or some columns omitted as in your example.

```
select * from rekap_teams.tblrekappendidikan_divisitahunan as t2014 join 
    rekap_teams.tblrekappendidikan_divisitahunan as t2015 on(DIVISI) 
    where t2014.year = 2014 and t2015.year=2015
```

Replace * with the order of the column names.

Comment: But his sample data does not have any groupings. They are just one entry per year.